# Numerical Solutions to PDEs with Financial Applications

Tags: options, numerical-methods, black-scholes-pde

I am reading a paper by Richard White, Opengamma named Numerical Solutions to PDEs with Financial Applications. There is an implementation codes as stated in paper hosted at https://opengamma.com/downloads/financial-pde-solving-matlab-examples.zip

Unfortunately the link is broken. Could you please share it with me if you have ?

Best,

You can get the paper at : https://quant.opengamma.io/PDE-solving5.pdf